# How to replace a string in a pandas multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe with a large multiindex, sourced from a vast number of csv files. Some of those files have errors in the various labels, ie. "window" is missspelled as "winZZw", which then causes problems when I select all windows with `df.xs('window', level='middle', axis=1)`.

So I need a way to simply replace `winZZw` with `window`.

Here's a very minimal sample df: (lets assume the data and the `'roof', 'window'…` strings come from some convoluted text reader)

```
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(['roof', 'window', 'basement'], names = ['top', 'middle', 'bottom'])
dates = pd.date_range('01/01/2000','01/12/2010', freq='MS')
data = np.random.randn(len(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dates, columns=header)
header2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(['roof', 'winZZw', 'basement'], names = ['top', 'middle', 'bottom'])
data = 3*(np.random.randn(len(dates)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dates, columns=header2)
df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
header3 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(['roof', 'door', 'basement'], names = ['top', 'middle', 'bottom'])
data = 2*(np.random.randn(len(dates)))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dates, columns=header3)
df = pd.concat([df, df3], axis=1)
```

Now I want to `xs` a new dataframe for all the *houses* that have a window at their middle level: `windf = df.xs('window', level='middle', axis=1)`

But this obviously misses the misspelled winZZw.

**So, how I replace `winZZw` with `window`?**

The only way I found was to use [set_levels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html?highlight=index%20set_levels#pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels), but if I understood that correctly, I need to feed it the whole level, ie

```
df.columns.set_levels([u'window',u'window', u'door'], level='middle',inplace=True)
```

but this has two issues:

- I need to pass it the whole index, which is easy in this sample, but impossible/stupid for a thousand column df with hundreds of labels.
- It seems to need the list backwards (now, my first entry in the df has door in the middle, instead of the window it had). That can probably be fixed, but it seems weird

I can work around these issues by `xs`ing a new df of only `winZZw`s, and then setting the levels with `set_levels(df.shape[1]*[u'window'], level='middle')` and then concatting it together again, but I'd like to have something more straightforward analog to `str.replace('winZZw', 'window')`, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: it seems the code contains error, please check first. `MultiIndex.from_product` needs list of list as input.

Comment: In @jezraels answer, he changed `['roof', 'window', 'basement']` to `[['roof'],[ 'window'], ['basement']]` to make it work. So perhaps you are using a pandas that is too old.

Comment: yep, that probably is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rename` with specifying level:

```
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['roof'],[ 'window'], ['basement']], names = ['top', 'middle', 'bottom'])
dates = pd.date_range('01/01/2000','01/12/2010', freq='MS')
data = np.random.randn(len(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dates, columns=header)
header2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['roof'], ['winZZw'], ['basement']], names = ['top', 'middle', 'bottom'])
data = 3*(np.random.randn(len(dates)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dates, columns=header2)
df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
header3 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['roof'], ['door'], ['basement']], names = ['top', 'middle', 'bottom'])
data = 2*(np.random.randn(len(dates)))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dates, columns=header3)
df = pd.concat([df, df3], axis=1)

df = df.rename(columns={'winZZw':'window'}, level='middle')
print(df.head())

top             roof                    
middle        window                door
bottom      basement  basement  basement
2000-01-01 -0.131052 -1.189049  1.310137
2000-02-01 -0.200646  1.893930  2.124765
2000-03-01 -1.690123 -2.128965  1.639439
2000-04-01 -0.794418  0.605021 -2.810978
2000-05-01  1.528002 -0.286614  0.736445
```

Comment: I admit, I forgot to test it with the sample, since it failed with `TypeError: rename() got an unexpected keyword argument "level"
` on my real data, which seemed to indicate to me that `rename` simply cant work on the index.

Comment: @JC_CL - Waht is your pandas version? Need `0.20.0+` - check [Addition of a level keyword to DataFrame/Series.rename to rename labels in the specified level of a MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-enhancements-other)

Comment: Damn, still on `0.18`. I really should not have started working with something that is not stable…

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution to replace a string within a multiindex is the following

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple([x.replace("to_replace", "new_str") for x in tuple_index]) for tuple_index in df.columns])
```